# How to make string interpolation in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to make string interpolation like in Ruby but in Javascript

```rb
name = "world"
puts "Hello, #{name}!"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use template literals by using ` (sorry, can't put it in block code) instead of `"` or `'`:

```js
let name = "world";
console.log("Hello, " + name); // Classical way
console.log(`Hello, ${name}`); // With template literals
```